# Open PopUp (kind of tableview) on UITabBaritem Click - iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

In my iPad (universal) application, i need to open a Popup view kind of table view with min three listing that should open a new UIView on click.

Is it possible to do that and How can i do it?

Comment: iPad or Universal (runs on both iPhone/iPod touch and iPad)? Only iPad has UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meeya, welcome to SO!

I recommend using the [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.  You can set the content inside the content popover to view a table view (UITableView).  When you click each, you can handle it the same way you'd handle any other table tap.

Comment: Can i open the popover on UITabbarItem click. Is there any chance that it will violate the apple rules?

Comment: That seems like unexpected behavior, and may well violate the UI guidelines. Usually popovers are attached to buttons in a toolbar or navigation bar.